# Foreach Accessing XML elements inside nodes

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have the following XML elements in a big file and I am trying to iterate thru the elements inside StayDateRange how can I accomplish this? I have other sections where I need to do something similar.

```
<StDteRange timeUnitType="DAY">
   <strtTime>2009-06-28T00:00:00.000</strtTime>
   <numOfUnits>4</numOfUnits>
</StDteRange >

IEnumerable<XElement> StDteRange = from el in root.Descendants(aw + "StDteRange ") 
select  el;

foreach (XElement el in StDteRange )
{
       if (el.Name.LocalName=="strtTime")
            Console.WriteLine((DateTime)el);

       if (el.Name=="numOfUnits")
            Console.WriteLine((int)el);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using serialization to navigate the data?

Comment: How you do that? Any advice it's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good examples online:

[Scott Guthrie's Blog - Using Linq to XML](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/07/using-linq-to-xml-and-how-to-build-a-custom-rss-feed-reader-with-it.aspx)

[Hooked On Linq - Linq to XML](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx)

You can create a simple class to hold your results and then in your linq query create new objects:

```
public class XMLResult()
{
    public string localname;
    public int Units;
}

IEnumerable<XMLResult> results = from el in root.Descendants(aw + "StDteRange ") 
     select new XMLResult() {
          Name = el.Element("strtTime").value,
          Units = el.Element("numOfUnits").value
     };
```

Comment: I am getting and empty object exception. Please advise

Comment: I had just posted some Psudo code, I've updated it slightly to include the actual element names so it might work, but was more trying to show you the process.